# How do I go about finding a font that says "safe, secure data"?

Tags: font-recommendation

does anyone have any suggestions for a font and type treatment that says "safe, secure data?"

to me, the 'safe' part means big, bulky, with perhaps a steel sheen, impenetrable.
however, the 'data' part means a more elegant styling. i have had difficulty finding such a font. i have a large font catalog and nothing seems to fit. i've also tried searching design sites for new fonts, but still haven't found anything that seems to fit.

i would appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: did you try to draw the phrase as you want it to look?

Comment: Comic sans practically screams secure.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful to see some of your ideas, as it is, this question feels really broad. Why don't you present some of your top choices?

Comment: Since you won't get much mileage with the question as originally phrased, especially without some examples, I've reworded it to something that may be easier to answer.

Comment: I think this is entirely too opinon-based to really be answered. Just because you may feel a sans serif conveys "safe, secure data" many others may not. I may feel a nice non-humanist, solid, serif, typeface does a better job.

Answer (score 6):

Fonts don't say anything that specific.

At most, they can give off a broad, general *vibe*. But in terms of saying anything specific, it's going to depend heavily on context.

For example Bodoni may say 'classic' in general, and when applied to the cover of Elle it now says something more specific: 'high fashion'.

Futura may say 'industrial' in general, and when used by Wes Anderson, it now says 'quirky Bill Murray'.

Fraktur may say 'Old Germany' in general, and when used by Scandinavians with Guitars, it now says 'this is a death metal band'.

Comic Sans may say 'casual' in general, and when actually used in any context, it now says 'we don't care enough about ourselves to pick a decent typeface'.

OK, that last example is a bit tongue-in-cheek. But hopefully you get the pattern.

So you're not going to find a typeface that says something as specific as 'safe, secure data' that type of meaning is only going to come with your help as you apply the particular typeface in context.

Comment: This is more comment than answer, don't you think? Your answers are among the most insightful on GD. Perhaps with the question rephrased, you could expand it.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson it is short. Let me try and expand upon it.

Comment: thank you all! you have all helped me immensely! sometimes i just hit a creative block; now i have plenty of ideas to move past it. i'm rebranding & creating a logo, splash & landing page. i'm going with 2 options: orbitron,which i like better than bank gothic, with metal stamp/monster truck/testosterone/'expendables' tough & also nice, happy "safe&sound" security /professional-corporate inconsolata or similar. thanks again guys!

Answer (score 3):

Is this for a header or for text? Just browsing through Google webfonts I found:

*For headers* maybe something like Ubuntu Condensed, Orbitron, or Titillium Web.
[image: header font sample screenshot]

---

*For bodies of text* maybe Inconsolata, Open Sans Condensed, or Abel
[image: text font sample screenshot]

---

I have to agree with Yisela, its hard to tell what you your going for without any examples.

At [RSA](https://www.rsaconference.com/) this year there was everything from high-gloss, extra-bold fonts that looked like they were a component from an F-18 to lightweight geometric fonts that were in keeping with flat UI(these seemed to be the majority), so finding the right font is going to be pretty subjective and you could really go either way.

Comment: thank you all! you have all helped me immensely! sometimes i just hit a block; now i have plenty of ideas to move past it. i'm rebranding & creating a logo, splash & landing page. i'm going with 2 options: orbitron,which i like better than bank gothic, with metal stamp/monster truck/testosterone/expendables tough & also nice, happy "safe&sound" security /professional-corporate inconsolata or similar. thanks again guys!