# Which font conveys a feeling of security and credibility when dealing with banking?

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

We are building a site which will include actions related to bank accounts and banking in general. We need a good font that conveys a feeling of security and credibility. It's preferred that the font will be widely supported in all websites, but not mandatory.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I go about finding a font that says "safe, secure data"?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30030/how-do-i-go-about-finding-a-font-that-says-safe-secure-data)

Comment: @Joonas Thanks but I looked at this question, but the fonts suggested there are more related to themes like data, computers and digital.

Comment: There are some well secured places such as Yuma, Folsom and Alcazar. Those are also names of some sturdy fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one way to approach this question is instead to ask yourself "Which fonts do not promote credibility?"

[image]

Thus, don't use frivolous fonts, handwriting fonts, decorated fonts, eroded fonts... you get the picture.

Something which is no-nonsense, clear and beautifully functional should be used.

[image]

Komental's answer about information, workflow and user interaction are fundamental to any impression of security; but a clear, sensible font which works well and identically on all platforms can only bolster that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such font that can convey such feelings. Good UX and fast operation would create a feeling that "this works". Be sure that actions make sense and leave the user informed about what is going to happen and when it happens, they should be sure that it happened correctly. This is what creates a feeling of credibility and security.

Answer (score 0):

Emotional congruency is very important when selecting the font. It is a basic concept of design.  We process the image based on the shapes and colors first. This creates an emotional framework by which everything else on the site is viewed. Just like the previous comment what does not work is a good start but you can look up what feelings the FONT was designed to convey. Next is font pairing, we use two fonts. In this question, you are trying to convey TWO feelings SECURITY and CREDITABILITY. The main font should convey SECURITY paired with a FONT for creditability for text on the website. Research, you can look the FEELINGS the FONT designer intended.

Answer (score 0):

Verdana is a good font that symbolizes professionalism, it should be a good pick.
Also take note of the colors you use in other covey a overall feeling of security.